# An online editor that allows data labeling format

Tags: natural-language-processing, datasets, data-labelling

I have a set of students (~20) that will work on annotating data for an NLP project.

The annotation task will be as in the following:

```
text: I like this piza place.
label: [pos, neg]
comments: 
text fluency: [1,2,3,4,5]
```

The students will need to correct the text first (e.g. correcting `piza` word), and then fill the fields below.

Is there an online solution to add the data in this format and then to share the link with the students?

I tried to do this in Google forum, but I wasn't able to; I don't know actually if it's possible there.

I am looking for a solution that can allow saving the edits after annotating # instances, as there are many instances and the students won't be able to annotate everything at once. I know that a good solution would be building a website, but I am looking for something that already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good folks behind Spacy have their paid product called [Prodigy](https://prodi.gy/) which is a data labeling tool. I haven't used it but it appears you can host it somewhere and then you would just have to send the link to the students. It is a little pricey but you get a lifetime license...

A free alternative might be [Label Studio](https://labelstud.io/) but I am not sure how easy it is to host it somewhere.

Hope this helps!